# Displaying and scrolling a UIImageView (image) that is longer than screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, autolayout

I have an image I want to display and it is longer than the screen size. The idea is I want it to scroll to show the entire image. I have created a `UIImageView` inside a `UIScrollView` and I can see the image in XCode but not when I run the app. Also even in XCode I am having trouble with the proportions - is this an issue caused by auto layout and maybe that is why when running the app in the simulator I do not see the image?

**edit** The image is in 16:9 portrait aspect ratio for iPhone 5+...I wan't it to fill the entire screen in terms of the part which is showing. i.e. the width is equal to screen size but the height is much longer and that is what I want to scroll...

Comment: Post how you have set up constraints between your image view and scroll view.

Comment: Scroll view constraints to view are 0 to all four edges and the image is the same relative to the scrollview...

Comment: Try settings the content compression resistance and content hugging priorities of the image view to 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your constraints are wrong. The are two different "sizes" on a UIScrollView. The frame and the content view. What your constraints are doing is setting the image to the frame that in turn fits in the view. What you need to do for the UIImage constraints is the following:

- Leading, top, trailing space to the scrollview should be 0 => this sets: x,y, and width
- Aspect ratio should be equal to your image's ratio => this sets hight

This will cause your image to have the "correct hight" and the contentView should adjust accordingly.